# How to remove index.php from the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I know it has been asked before but I have tried everything and it still won't work. Maybe it has to do with the new version of CodeIgniter 3?

My file structure is like this:

```
blue(public_html)
    --index.php
    --.htaccess

code_igniter
   --application
   --system
```

`.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the URL you use to access this system? Just curious to see if you've got everything else working as you've plonked the application and system folders under another folder called code_igniter.

Comment: Can you also show your .htaccess file and where that lives.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw http://localhost/blue/

Comment: Is mod rewrite enabled on your server ?

Comment: Does everything work when you include index.php in the URL? For the above folder structure you would have edited your index.php $system_path and $application_folder to reflect the changes as they are not in the same folder as index.php!

Comment: *Maybe it has to do with the new version of CodeIgniter 3?*  ~ No, this has nothing to do with version 3.  Something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Apache as your web server with ModRewrite enabled, there are a few things you need to get this set up correctly within CodeIgniter:
 1. A correctly written `.htaccess`
 2. A valid `application/config/config.php` file
 3. A valid `index.php` file.

Let's go over these one by one.

#### `.htaccess` configuration

In your example, you are missing your `RewriteBase` declaration. You need to add that declaration with the absolute path to your publicly accessible directory. This is the `.htaccess` file in the base of the public directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /absolute/path/to/blue(public_html)/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### `config.php` configuration

In `application/config/config.php` you need to make sure you've set your `base_url` and `index_page` options correctly. To remove `index.php` from the URL, you must set the `index_page` option to blank.

```
/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|---------------------------------------------------------------
*/
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/blue';

/*
|---------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|---------------------------------------------------------------
*/

$config['index_page'] = ''; // <-- note that this is empty!
```

#### `index.php` configuration

Your `index.php` configuration file lives in the root of the publicly accessible directory. Here, you need to set the absolute paths to your application and system folders.

```
/*
*---------------------------------------------------------------
* SYSTEM FOLDER NAME
*---------------------------------------------------------------
...
*/
$system_path = '/absolute/path/to/code_igniter/system';

/*
*---------------------------------------------------------------
* APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
*---------------------------------------------------------------
...
*/
$application_folder = '/absolute/path/to/code_igniter/application';
```

Once you have those three things fixed in CI, you should be able to hit **localhost/blue** without `index.php` in the URL.